# Allowing multiple accounts when signing in with Google+

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus

For my app, I followed the example on [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button) to sign in using Google+, but it signs the user in and calls the `signinCallback` whenever the page loads. But I don't want it to sign in automatically on the page load and more importantly, I need to give the user a chance to choose between his different Google accounts.

When I log the user out using `gapi.auth.signOut()` and then reload the page containing this button, it *still* signs me in automatically. This doesn't allow the user a chance to sign in with a different google account.

The Gmail workflow seems to be to log me in automatically, but gives me an option once logged in to "Add account" which goes to [this page.](https://accounts.google.com/AddSession?hl=en&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail&service=mail)

But when I try to change the continue url to my service it gives me an `"invalid page request"` error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but I was just looking for this answer and figured something out.

There are two options that I know of, one is to use the [sign out](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/sign-out) flow. The next time the user logs in, they will be prompted to do user selection.

The second is to set [data-approvalprompt](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference) to force. That will force the user selection and could be used to switch the user.